# MySql Insert signal if where clause fails

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, signals

As part of a chained sequence of transactional queries, I'm inserting values that exist in a temporary table into a new table.

Every query is validated for errors in PHP using:

```
if (!mysqli_query($dbc, ....) {$errors[] = mysqli_error($dbc);}
```

If an error occurs it gets pushed into the errors array and the entire sequence is not commited.

With this approach I'm having trouble validating for queries that **DO NOT CAUSE AN ERROR** but **DO NOT MEET WHERE CLAUSE CONDITIONS**

Is there a way to get MySQL to throw an error signal when the **WHERE CLAUSE** conditions are not met?